# A cuestión about Piwik

Tags: configuration, matomo

first of all I'm new with Piwik.

I would like to know if I can have a single Piwik installation for different 
customers websites with this cases:

- Customer 1 with a web site.
- Customer 2 with a web site.
- Customer 3 with a few web sites.
- ....
- ....

Also I'd like to know if I can save the information from Piwik in different databases that can be in different servers?  I mean, a database for a domain or subdomain and have at the same time a server for every database.

I know that it's a strange question, but we want to be really for all kind of situations.

Thanks.

Oskar

Answer (score 0):

I have check that can be create users, domain and let users to check some domains.